# How do I run git update-index skip-worktree from nodeJS sccript

Tags: node.js, git

I know that git update-index skip-worktree can be used to ignore a file from any changes. I don't want to run this command manually on every system, how can I write a node js script to do this with a npm command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have approaches for formatting code ([here](http://engineering.monsanto.com/2018/09/26/using-prettier/) or in [`okonet/lint-staged` issue 170](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/170#issuecomment-373905499) which takes advantages of a [`script` section of a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

You could use that for instance in the prepare step, which is run both *before* the package is packed and published, on local `npm install` without any arguments, and when installing git dependencies.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "git update-index --skip-worktree -- afile",
  }
}
```

Comment: The command fails on my mac, adding extra `--` fix this: `git update-index --skip-worktree -- afile`. My git version is 2.21.0.

Comment: @EviSong thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.