# How to run lerna publish on Travis with modifying .npmrc file?

Tags: javascript, git, travis-ci, lerna, monorepo

I try to redesign my component lib into a monorepo. I chose lerna for this. 
All worked fine until I tried to connect it to Travis CI.

There is one trick I do on Travis you need to be aware of first. 
I use private NPM registry for one of the dependencies, I also store my lib in the same place.

So for the development purposes I have a token stored in .npmrc file with read-only access in the code base.
The token with publish rights is kept in Travis and when the jobs are run there I override the .npmrc content with the Travis token.

It all worked fine (for NPM publish) until I switched to lerna.

Now when I run lerna publish, I can see a message that:

```
lerna ERR! EUNCOMMIT Working tree has uncommitted changes, 
           please commit or remove the following changes before continuing:
lerna ERR! EUNCOMMIT  M .npmrc
```

I tried to add .npmrc to .gitignore but it's undoable. I need to modify this file, I don't want to keep it in repo. 
How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A thought came to my mind while writing this. 
Can I commit it and then just forget about it? It will be destroyed together with Travis's VM that runs the job - right?

Comment: You had selected the right answer below. What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can commit in your Travis-build, as [illustrated by this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mitchellkrogza/a296ab5102d7e7142cc3599fca634203).

You only need to be careful, and not create a Travis CI fork bomb(!): see [`travis-ci/travis-ci` issue 1701](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1701).

The other approach is a to add a `"prepare": "git update-index --skip-worktree -- .npmrc",` script step in your `package.json`, in order to force a file to ignore its modification.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762296/6309).

Comment: The `prepare` command fails on my mac, adding extra `--` fix this: `git update-index --skip-worktree -- .npmrc`. My git version is 2.21.0.

Comment: @EviSong Thank you (again). I have edited the answer.